# Get Element by Selector or Class Name

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

Challenge:
I have several links with collections of products, and I need to fill the next column with the number of followers of these collections. The number of followers is generated by JavaScript and I swear `IMPORTXML` doesn't work here. I'm not techy, but I think I obviously need some script that will go by the link and bring me the data. But I googled some time and couldn't find any similar solutions or tasks, so I decided to go here and ask for help.

Is there any way, besides `IMPORTXML`, to get a specific element on the webpage? Whether already exists some function that can take URL and return a specific element?

Comment: Try `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)`

Comment: Can you share some sample links.

Comment: The way you can extract this information would depend on how the data is laid out. Could you maybe share an information about the HTML page? Have you looked in [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)? 
And as @Cooper have said, you could actually use [`fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)).